# Error al ejecutar consulta (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, function

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE hola VARCHAR(255);
   SET hola = (SELECT codigo FROM estudiante WHERE semestre = prmSemestre);
   RETURN hola;
END
```

[Problem Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAjuj.png)

How can i solved it?

Comment: Add limit 1 to the select or change the select to ensure you only bring back 1 record or rethink what you are trying to do(possibly enriching the question to give us a hint).

Comment: But i need More than one register.

Comment: You cannot stuff multiple items into a variable. Can you explain what you are trying to do adding sample data and expected results as text to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something like this

```
+----------+------+----------------------+
| SudentID | Name | courses              |
+----------+------+----------------------+
|        1 | abc  | 1 Geog,2 Hist,3 Chem |
|        2 | def  | 2 Hist               |
|        3 | ghi  | 2 Hist,3 Chem        |
+----------+------+----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And your model looks something like this

```
ariaDB [sandbox]> select sudentid,name from student where sudentid < 4;
+----------+------+
| sudentid | name |
+----------+------+
|        1 | abc  |
|        2 | def  |
|        3 | ghi  |
+----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from courses;
+------+------+
| ID   | NAME |
+------+------+
|    1 | Geog |
|    2 | Hist |
|    3 | Chem |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from studentcourses;
+------+------+
| Sid  | Cid  |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
|    2 |    2 |
|    3 |    2 |
|    3 |    3 |
+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then a group_concat would do

```
select s.SudentID,s.Name,
        (select group_concat(c.id,' ',c.name) from StudentCourses sc join Courses c on sc.cid = c.id 
        where sc.sid = s.sudentid
        group by sc.sid) courses
from student s
where sudentid < 4
;
```